# How do I specify my data type in mongoose if the data is a video file?

Tags: javascript, types, mongoose-schema

[image: Screenshot of my front end collecting the data]

I am trying to create a basic web page for a online class and I am stuck in the adding the video to my MongoDB. I have specified the code below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let lecture = new Schema({
**LectureName:{ type:String },
LectureDescription:{ type:String },
LectureVideo:{ type:Schema.Types.Mixed }** //I need help on this line
},
{
collection: 'Lecture'
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Lecture',lecture);
```

Can anyone tell me what will be the type of data in mongoose schema for a video attachment? Thank You!

Comment: How are you encoding the file?

Comment: Sorry, @sinanspd what do you mean by that?

Comment: Mongo is not a file system. You can not just drop a file in there and expect it to work. The binary data of the file has to be encoded properly to be stored. Depending on how you choose to handle it, it would be a `Buffer` or `String`. Also note that you can not store anything larger than 16MB in Mongo. You will need to chunk the file using `gridFS` or use something else entirely

Comment: Oh thank you for letting me know @sinanspd